# Set href of <a> tag within angular-ui bootstrap pagination module

Tags: angularjs, seo, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

for SEO purposes, I want to crawl my angular application to create html snapshots. Is there a way to set set the "href" attribute of the anchor tags of the pagination directive.

An ideal method would be to take a base URL as a parameter and append the page number:

```
"http://www.somesite.com/products/" + page
```

My current pagination directive implementation looks like this:

```
<pagination 
    total-items="grid.totalCount" 
    items-per-page="grid.pageSize"
    ng-model="grid.pageNumber" 
    force-ellipses="true" 
    max-size="7" 
    class="pagination-sm  hidden-xs hidden-sm" 
    rotate="false"
    boundary-links="true"
    first-text="1"
    last-text="{{ grid.pageCount }}"
    ng-class="{
        'remove-boundaries': grid.pageCount <= 7, 
        'remove-first-boundaries': grid.pageNumber <= 7, 
        'remove-last-boundaries': grid.pageNumber >= grid.pageCount - 7 
}">
</pagination>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to extend the directive (decorate it, an example [here](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)) and override the click event to perform your request to the server.

Edit:
Something similar to this:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('paneDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        angular.extend(directive.scope, {
            disabled:'@'
        });
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

This example above extends the pane directive and adds to the directive scope a property 'disabled.'

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The answer itself actually explains what are the steps. Link is only an example. But, ok will ad some piece of code as example.